# Avalon 741 and/or later models without AUC3 converter?

Tags: mining-hardware, raspberry-pi, avalon

Avalon models prior to the 741 normally required an AUC2 converter to work, but it was also possible to bypass that requirement by plugging the miner's data cable directly into a Raspberry Pi's IIC pins (as explained for example [here](https://www.cryptouniverse.at/run-avalon-6-miner-without-auc2-converter/)).

Is it possible to do the same with any of the later models (741 or later - and if yes, which ones)? Ie is it possible to simply plug any of the models that normally require an AUC3 converter directly to a Raspberry Pi's IIC pins instead (and if yes, which ones)?